# Android geolocation works in 2.2, but not 2.3

Tags: android, android-emulator, geolocation, android-sdk-2.3

I was hoping someone could shed some light on this.  I'm trying to figure out why all of a sudden my code from 2.2 will not work with 2.3.  I'm a little bit puzzled.  This is the code that has been working, but is now throwing a null pointer exception.

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location l){
        Log.i("MYSERVICE", "LocationChanged " + l);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle Extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        Log.i("MYSERVICE", "ProviderEnabled " + provider);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    String location = getLocation();
}


public String getLocation() {
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Log.i("lat", lat.toString());
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    String writeString = lat+"&"+lng;
    return writeString;
}

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I am using a 2.3 emulator as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`getLastKnownLocation` can return null if there is no previous location. If so, you need to wait for the value in `onLocationChanged` with the listener you registered.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that android 2.3 does not work with "0,0" on `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);`

You need to set those 2 parameters to at least 1 and 1:
`lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);`

Comment: This is just wrong. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html): If minTime is greater than 0, the LocationManager could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds between location updates to conserve power. If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcast if the device moves by minDistance meters. **To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.**

Comment: Why did you voted negative? Yes it's true that to obtain notifications as frequently as possible you must set both to 0, but on 2.3 Gingerbread DOESN'T WORK!!!! I tried this, and on 2.2(Froyo) worked, but on 2.3 didn't worked.

Comment: I voted down because it _does_ work. It works on the emulator, it works on my device, and according to the docs it has worked ever since API level 1. If you're going to claim that the documentation is just straight up wrong, it would be best to provide some evidence. Otherwise, it's best to assume something's wrong with code or wrong with device.